# Probability - Definition

Tags: probability

> Probability
>
> = $\dfrac{\text{Number of favorable outcomes}}{\text{ total number of outcome}}$

The above definition is taken from my textbook and also available in many websites.

But, after doing many questions in probability and got some understanding on this, I got a doubt on the definition stated above.

Won't the definition of probability assume that all the outcomes are equally likely?

In other words, we cannot apply this definition when all outcomes are not equally likely.

In that case, do we have a more detailed definition of probability or Am I wrong in my understanding?

Please help.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  To get to the next level you need to know the frequency distribution of your events.

Comment: This is only one 'definition' - there have been many attempts to define what a probability is. The mathematician's way out of this is to say that probability is some measure on sets satisfying some rules. Your definition does satisfy those rules under some conditions, so it defines a probability but, as you say, this does not help you decide some odds for the 2.30 horse race at Kempton..

Comment: @Doug M, thanks. the problem with me is when I do many problems, I am getting more and more doubts like this and it is not ending :(. Now it is clear.  Going to learn frequency distribution, though might be above my level now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a definition of probability. It's the [principle of indifference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_indifference), and as you correctly state, it only applies when the outcomes can be assumed to be equiprobable.

Mathematically speaking, probability can be grounded on [probability axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms). How these relate to reality is the subject of [probability interpretations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_interpretations), of which there are many.

Comment: thanks for that. But, please see the book https://books.google.co.in/books?id=domrBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA571&dq=probability+definition+number+of+favourable+outcomes&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi55oLL6OHMAhUEpI8KHQa7AEgQ6AEIKjAD#v=onepage&q=probability%20definition%20number%20of%20favourable%20outcomes&f=false  . It is given as definition of probability. Many books in my level define probability like this only. Can you please tell me why this happens?

Comment: @Kiran: That's a terrible book. It would be bad enough if it presented you with that "definition" if at least it stuck with it throughout the book and used only examples that fit within that paradigm. But only three pages later in Example $7$ they talk about the probability of someone winning a tennis match being $0.62$, which is obviously not due to anything like one of $62$ favourable outcomes out of a total of $100$ outcomes occurring.

Comment: thanks for taking time and helping. I always encountered situations like this and therefore I use websites to solve more problems. This website is always helpful and I uses most to get my doubts cleared.

Comment: @Kiran: As to why this happens: I guess it's because they want to make it as simple and concrete as possible and don't want to talk about probability spaces or the like. But the least they could do would be to say something like "In a broader context, probability is defined through a set of axioms, but here we'll use a simple definition that applies in cases of equiprobable outcomes."

Comment: yes, that could be their reasoning. Perhaps, they  wanted to add more details only in higher classes. However, it was helpful if these textbooks have given some pointers to concepts like set of axioms etc, like you mentioned, because it would have helped in understanding probability  more